# How to continue execution after traceback error

Tags: python, python-3.x

sometime i got

```
Traceback '(most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 899, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'example@gmail.com': (550, b'The mail server could not deliver mail to example@gmail.com.  The account\nor domain may not exist, they may be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns\nentries.')}'
```

and script get stopped
i need to know if there solution to continue after any error

```
with smtplib.SMTP(smtpsv, port) as server:

server.starttls() # Secure the connection

server.login(user, password)
server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
print(" + {}: {} sent succeffully".format(count, line.strip()))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], which has tips like starting with your own research. If you just paste your question title into google, you get useful results, and I've closed this question under one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement **try/except** to handle error without breaking the flow,

```
import traceback
try:
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtpsv, port) as server:
        server.starttls() # Secure the connection

        server.login(user, password)
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
        print(" + {}: {} sent succeffully".format(count, line.strip()))
except Exception:
    print(traceback.print_exc())
```

Comment: [A bare `except` is bad practice](/q/54948548/4518341). Instead, use the specific exception you're expecting like `except smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused`, or at least `except Exception`.

Comment: @wjandrea You are right, modified the above example

Answer (score 0):

just wrap particular function /code in try execpt block

```
try:
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtpsv, port) as server:

        server.starttls()  # Secure the connection

        server.login(user, password)
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
        print(" + {}: {} sent succeffully".format(count, line.strip()))
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```